# Examples of UNIX Domain Socket Usage

Tags: unix, sockets

Can anyone give an example of instances in which the AF_UNIX i.e unix domain sockets are used for process communication in a unix-based system

Comment: Why the downvotes - it is a reasonable question about a programming API that can be answered precisely. OK its very *nix specific, but, considering at least half of all the servers in the world are running some variation of unix  it does not seem too specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X windows uses unix sockets when you run application locally (on the same host as the X server) and tcp for remote application. MySQL programs also uses unix sockets to connect to a local server.

Answer (score 0):

`socketpair` is great to communicate with a child process. With `SEQ_PACKET` mode you need to do very little framework, just work on the meat.